# ruby how to add a hash element into an existing json array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I have code that outputs the following:

```
car_id = ["123"]
model = [:model].product(car_id).map { |k,v| {k=>v} }
model = [{:model=>"123"}]
```

I would like to then add a new hash `:make` into the json like this:

```
model_with_make = [{:model=>"123", :make => "acura"}]
```

How do I do this?

Unfortunately, every solution I find produces this:
`[{:model=>"123"}, {:make => "acura"}]` and that is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ruby convention for showing result of a calculation**

I assume you mean that

```
model = [:model].product(car_id).map { |k,v| {k=>v} }
```

produces an array containing a single hash:

```
[{:model=>"123"}]
```

and that you are not then executing the statement:

```
model = [{:model=>"123"}]
```

which would overwrite the the value of `model` from the previous statement, rendering the previous statement meaningless. If so, the normal way to write that is as follows.

```
model = [:model].product(car_id).map { |k,v| {k=>v} }
  #=> [{:model=>"123"}]
```

**Computing the array**

Next,

```
arr = [:model].product(car_id)
  #=> [[:model, "123"]]
```

But why use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-product) when the arrays `[:model]` and `car_id` both contain a single element? It's simpler to just write

```
arr = [[:model, car_id.first]]
  #=> [[:model, "123"]]
```

**Converting the array to a hash**

Since `arr` contains only one element, there's not much point to `map`ping it; just convert it to a hash:

```
Hash[arr]
  #=> {:model=>"123"}
```

or (for Ruby versions 1.9+):

```
arr.to_h
  #=> {:model=>"123"}
```

**Add a key-value pair to the hash**

If you wish to add the key-value pair `:make => "acura"` to

```
h = {:model=>"123"}
```

you can simply write

```
h[:make] = "acura"
  #=> "acura" 
h #=> {:model=>"123", :make=>"acura"}
```

or, in one line,

```
(h[:make] = "acura") && h
  #=> {:model=>"123", :make=>"acura"}
```

**Wrapping up**

Putting this together, you could write

```
h = [[:model, car_id.first]].to_h
  #=> {:model=>"123"} 
(h[:make] = "acura") && h
  #=> {:model=>"123", :make=>"acura"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
model = [{:model=>"123"}]
model_with_make = model.map { |m| m.merge(make: 'acura') }
#⇒ [{:model=>"123", :make => "acura"}]
```

If you are concerned that there is the only element in the array `model`, you might modify it inplace:

```
model.first.merge!(make: 'acura')
model
#⇒ [{:model=>"123", :make => "acura"}]
```